# Canvas Data Lost when Mobile Orientation Change

Tags: canvas

I am trying to resize my canvas on change of device orientation in mobile web view. I'm using the below code:

```
 $(window).resize(function ()
 {
    $('#wPaint_181_17').css({ 
        width: $(window).width(),
        height: $(window).height()
     });
 });
```

In my canvas area I have an image and I draw something on it, it's working fine.
I change orientation of device and call this method to resize the canvas, it works: image is resized.

But now when I'm using any canvas tool to draw on image , then the coordinates are shifting.
If I'm drawing on left area then it's viewed shifted towards more right.

If I reload my page then it works fine, but I can't reload the page because I have some other data entered by user on the page and also previous changes done in Canvas image which I need to store on change of device orientation.

Comment: Don't set your canvas width and height through CSS, use its `.width` and `.height` properties instead.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you'll have to save that data thats set and set it again  in the on orientation change section.